# How can I make the MT7601U Wireless Adapter work in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

I almost tried to follow the tutorials and threads on the internet but my wireless adapter is still not working. I am now worried because I think I installed a lot which might cause some errors to my computer. I am fairly new to Ubuntu or Linux.

I tried `rfkill list all` and `sudo modprobe mt7601u` but it returns nothing.

I tried `dmesg | grep mt76` and it returned 5 results:

```
[  510.404246] mt7601u 2-4:1.0: ASIC revision: 76010001 MAC revision: 76010500
[  510.406804] mt7601u 2-4:1.0: loading /lib/firmware/mt7601u.bin failed with error -22
[  510.406814] mt7601u 2-4:1.0: Direct firmware load for mt7601u.bin failed with error -22
[  510.407530] mt7601u: probe of 2-4:1.0 failed with error -22
[  510.407616] usbcore: registered new interface driver mt7601u
```

Which doesn't make sense to me at all.

I really need help in order to use my computer for web-dev course.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 3):

Your dmesg clearly shows that the driver failed to load the required firmware. First, is the firmware present in the expected place?

```
ls /lib/firmware | grep mt76
```

We hope that you see:

```
mt7601u.bin
```

...among others. If it is not present, get a temporary working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware
```

Reboot. Now is your wireless working as expected?

If the firmware file *is* found from the command above, perhaps the permissions are incorrect. Check:

```
ls -al  /lib/firmware/mt7601u.bin
```

We hope you see:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 45412 Mar 19 12:37 /lib/firmware/mt7601u.bin
```

That is, readable by all and writable only by root. If that is not what you find, repair it:

```
sudo chmod 0644 /lib/firmware/mt7601u.bin
```

Reboot. Now is your wireless working as expected?

If the firmware file is found and has the correct permissions,perhaps it is corrupted. Check:

```
md5sum  /lib/firmware/mt7601u.bin
```

We hope you see:

```
696cedb8e76ecc0cda9f9b0d3972c64d  /lib/firmware/mt7601u.bin
```

If you see anything different, reinstall linux-firmware as above and reboot. If it is *still* not working, again show us in an edit:

```
dmesg | grep mt76
```